# Create a function to get column from multiple tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a function to get a field value from multiple tables in my database. I made script like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_changes() RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
$$
DECLARE 
  tblname VARCHAR;
  tblrow RECORD;
  row RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR tblrow IN SELECT tablename FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE schemaname='public' LOOP /*FOREACH tblname IN ARRAY $1 LOOP*/
      RAISE NOTICE 'r: %', tblrow.tablename;
      FOR row IN SELECT MAX("lastUpdate") FROM tblrow.tablename LOOP
          RETURN NEXT row;
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;

SELECT get_all_changes();
```

But it is not working, everytime it shows this error

```
tblrow.tablename" not defined in line "FOR row IN SELECT MAX("lastUpdate") FROM tblrow.tablename LOOP"
```

Comment: Don't use quotes for the language name. It's an identifier, not a string. [The manual says](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html): `For backward compatibility, the name can be enclosed by single quotes`. But really, you shouldn't. Just `LANGUAGE plpgsql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your new question (mislabeled as answer):

This can be much simpler. You do *not* need to create a table just do define a record type.
If at all, you would better create a type with `CREATE TYPE`, but that's only efficient if you need the type in multiple places. For just a single function, you can use [**`RETURNS TABLE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) instead :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_changes(text[])
 RETURNS TABLE (tablename text
               ,"lastUpdate" timestamp with time zone
               ,nums integer) AS
$func$
DECLARE 
    tblname text;
BEGIN
    FOREACH tblname IN ARRAY $1 LOOP
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
        $f$SELECT '%I', MAX("lastUpdate"), COUNT(*)::int FROM %1$I
        $f$, tblname)
    END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### A couple more points:

- Use [`RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) instead of the nested loop. Much simpler and faster.
- Column aliases would only serve as documentation, those names are discarded in favor of the names declared in the `RETURNS` clause (directly or indirectly).
- Use [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) with `%I` to replace the concatenation with `quote_ident()` and `%1$I` to refer to the same parameter another time.
- `count()` usually returns type `bigint`. Cast the integer, since you defined the column in the return type as such: `count(*)::int`.

Comment: Erwin, Thank you for help. I finally use CREATE TYPE instead of table. It will raise an error when use 'RETURN QUERY', I don't know why.

Comment: Create a new question. If it helps, add a link to this one for context. In the new question, provide your function definition, your version of PostgreSQL and the exact error message. You can run `SET lc_messages = 'C'` to get default English error messages if you are running a different locale.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner `FOR` loop must use the `FOR...EXECUTE` syntax as shown in the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING):

```
FOR target IN EXECUTE text_expression [ USING expression [, ... ] ] LOOP
    statements
END LOOP [ label ];
```

In your case something along this line:

```
FOR row IN EXECUTE 'SELECT MAX("lastUpdate") FROM ' || quote_ident(tblrow.tablename) LOOP
   RETURN NEXT row;
END LOOP
```

The reason for this is explained in the [manual somewhere else](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

> Oftentimes you will want to generate dynamic commands inside your PL/pgSQL functions, that is, commands that will involve different tables or different data types each time they are executed. PL/pgSQL's normal attempts to cache plans for commands (as discussed in Section 39.10.2) will not work in such scenarios. To handle this sort of problem, the EXECUTE statement is provided[...]

Comment: Better written as `IN EXECUTE format('SELECT max("lastUpdate") FROM %I',tblrow.tablename) LOOP` ... or at least use `|| quote_ident(tblrow.tblname)`. Otherwise bang on.

Comment: @CraigRinger: TNX for pointing out. I fixed the answer using `quote_ident`, since `format` exists only since 9.1.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
I finally made my script like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS __rsdb_changes (tablename text,"lastUpdate" timestamp with time zone, nums bigint);
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_changes(varchar[]) RETURNS SETOF __rsdb_changes AS  /*TABLE (tablename varchar(40),"lastUpdate" timestamp with time zone, nums integer)*/
    $$
    DECLARE 
      tblname VARCHAR;
      tblrow RECORD;
      row RECORD;
    BEGIN
        FOREACH tblname IN ARRAY $1 LOOP
          /*RAISE NOTICE 'r: %', tblrow.tablename;*/
          FOR row IN EXECUTE 'SELECT CONCAT('''|| quote_ident(tblname) ||''') AS tablename, MAX("lastUpdate") AS "lastUpdate",COUNT(*) AS nums FROM ' || quote_ident(tblname) LOOP
            /*RAISE NOTICE 'row.tablename: %',row.tablename;*/
            /*RAISE NOTICE 'row.lastUpdate: %',row."lastUpdate";*/
            /*RAISE NOTICE 'row.nums: %',row.nums;*/
            RETURN NEXT row;
          END LOOP;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN;
    END
    $$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

Well, it works. But it seems I can only create a table to define the return structure instead of just RETURNS SETOF RECORD. Am I right?

Thanks again.

Comment: Did you read my comment about quoting the language name? Also, this is *not an answer*, but a new question.